# Errors in the code after build using angular cli (ng build)

Tags: angular, express

I am new angular, trying to set up new project in angular, using angular/cli. I did following steps to setup a express server and angular as the front end.

installed angular/cli; then 
ng new testApp;
ng build;
this created a dist folder like dist>testApp>and all the files(index,html, main.js. . . . so on),

and i have installed express and body-parser. now in my server.js i have following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/testApp/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.port || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port : ${port}`));
```

Now when i started the server and tried "http://localhost:3000/" on my browser I see errors in console saying unexpected token in all .js files like main.js, polyfills.js so when i look at the sources tab i can see even the js files are having the same index.html content in them.

So can any tell me what i was missing or doing the wrong way. please.
Thanks.

Comment: In your server.js all get requests are pointing to index.html, thats why you are getting all files with index.html contents. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite your server.js file as below.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));


app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'testApp')));


const port = process.env.port || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port : ${port}`));
```

This may solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it solved my issue. but when i use                                  
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'testApp'));
});    it gives me "can not Get" , so shouldn't i be using res.send file or is it some thing else that i am doing?

Comment: You need not use `app.get` for showing the angular site. `app.get` or `app.post` can be used for API calls which your angular site needs.